# Solving a Second-Order Linear Equation (Non-zero RHS)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading Mary L. Boas' Mathematical methods in the Physical sciences. I am considering an auxiliary equation of form:
$$(D-a)(D-b)y=ke^{x},$$
where k and c are constant.

I know that a general solution to a second order DE can be given by the sum of a complementary function with a particular solution.

**This is my problem:**

In the book, it states that a particular solution of the above auxiliary equation can be assumed to be:
$$Ce^{cx},$$
if c is not equal to a or b (a $\neq$ b).
OR
$$Cxe^{cx},$$
if c is equal to a or b (a $\neq$ b).
OR
$$Cx^2e^{cx},$$
if c=a=b.

I am doing Problem 8.6.3 in the book, which asks me to solve:
$$y''+y'-2y=e^{2x},$$
I have simplified this to:
$$(D-1)(D+2)y=e^{2x}.$$
In this situation, it initially made sense for me to assume a solution of:
$$Ce^{2x},$$
This gave me a particular solution of:$$\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}.$$
Which, from what I can see online, is correct.
However, if I was going by what was in the book, I surely would assume a solution of $$cxe^{cx},$$ or $$2xe^{2x},$$ to match the power of the RHS. I'm clearly misunderstanding what the book is suggesting. I was just wondering if someone could explain where I can use those 3 assumed particular solutions/ why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"From what I can see online". Of course I have no idea what you refer to.

Your particular solution $\frac14\,e^{2x}$ is correct. And it's exactly what the book tells you to do.

Had $2$ being a root of your characteristic equation, you would have needed $Cxe^{2x}$, or even with $x^2$ if $2$ is a double root.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, what was confusing me however, cxe^{2x} is not of form cxe^{cx}, otherwise c would have to be 2 surely?  and it'd be 2xe^{2x}, which i know is wrong

Comment: Sorry, I am a complete idiot. I just realised it is Cxe^{cx} and C $\neq$ c. Thanks for your help :)